# Excel VBA Argument Not Optional Error in Change Event

Tags: excel, vba

I have put together the code below but get and "Argument not optional" error on this line:

```
If Rs >= 2 And Range.Value("Q2") = 0.2 Then
```

Can anyone see what the issue is?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Rs As Long

If Range("B2").Value = 1 And Range("Q2").Value = 0.2 Then Exit Sub
  Rs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A5"), "<10")
  If Rs >= 2 And Range.Value("Q2") = 0.2 Then
   Range("B2").Value = 1
  Else
   Range("B2").Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range("Q2").value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim Rs%
  If (Target.Column = 1) and (Target.Row < 6) Then
    If Not ((Range("B2").Value = 1) And (Range("Q2").Value2 = 0.2)) Then 
      Rs = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A5"), "<10")
      If Rs >= 2 And Range("Q2").Value2 = 0.2 Then
        Range("B2").Formula = 1
      Else
        Range("B2").ClearContents
      End If
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

It was saying the address of your range was omitted (because the "Q2" was put too late in that line).

You can find the documentation for this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value

Comment: Thanks guys. I have corrected it but now Excel crashes when it is triggered. Is there another issue?

Comment: A few tweaks, try revised code block in answer.

Comment: Thanks ed2. It's strange, it's still crashing. I can't see what the issue is

Comment: Hmmm try now, I made one more change to troubleshoot, in line 2 the variable `Rs` is now an integer to see if it's that, also removed the `exit sub` and reworked the `if` accordingly... but I doubt it will fix it

Comment: I'd suspect you need to disable events while changing the value in B2, in case it triggers a recalculation and therefore recursion of your code.

Comment: Try specifying Target range to limit the triggering of this code to (a) only the cells you want to watch and (b) not the ones it is changing. See edited block (function changed to worksheet change instead of worksheet calculate)

Comment: The `Calculate` event doesn't accept arguments, so can't use `Target` in there. You're also missing an `End If` as you removed the `Exit Sub`.  Changing `Long` to `Integer` shouldn't do anything - sure I've read somewhere that VBA changes Int to Long anyway.  On a personal note - I find using `%` for integer obfuscates the code a bit.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thanks, the Calculate Target issue was a work in progress on the way to what you now see. Thanks for picking End If, now fixed. Agree re Long and Integer, tried it on the 1/1^1000000 chance that it was crashing it (an approach that works more often that i'd otherwise expect!). Regarding%, agree but old habits die hard!

Comment: That's fixed it. Thanks for all the help